# Will Lion download from Mac App Store resume if network connection interrupted?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I'm contemplating downloading it but I'm in an area prone to connectivity outages. Or does it install a pre-loader which then downloads the actual disk image (which I can curl)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App applications downloaded from the App Store will automatically resume if your network service is interrupted. The Lion download is a DVD sized .dmg file that contains the OS, not a pre-loader.

If your download does get interrupted you can <kbd>control</kbd> + click on the Lion icon in your dock then click resume.

Comment: Unfortunately, experiences may vary...  My flaky Internet connection disconnects every now and then for a couple of seconds (every 200-300 downloaded megabytes approximately), just enough to make the download fail.  And, once every 2-3 times, the download starts from the beginning.

Comment: I had a similar issue: with Lion about 40% downloaded, I allowed Software Update to reboot the system to apply the SL 10.6.8 upgrade.  When I logged back in, Lion started from 0%. :(